# Intermittent CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR hitting server behind an AWS ALB

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

Configuration:

- Node.js Express server sitting behind an AWS ALB with certain routes
  protected using keycloak-connect (Keycloak Node.js adapter)
- The Express servers are running in a Kubernetes (EKS) cluster with two nodes
- The OIDC client (named 'camp') is access type = confidential

My server serves some static Web pages and a GraphQL API. Certain Web pages need to be protected which I do like so:

```
keycloak = new Keycloak({cookies: true}, kcConfig);

app.get('/my/web/page', keycloak.protect('admin'), (req, res, next) => {
  next('route'); 
});
```

This code should check that the authenticated user has the admin role and then pass control to the static web page at /my/web/page.

When I initially hit that route, I am correctly redirected to the Keycloak login page. However, after authenticating I get a 403. In my application log, I see the message: "Could not obtain grant code: Error: 400:Bad Request"

In the Keycloak log, I see:

```
16:23:28,651 INFO [org.keycloak.events] (default task-428) type=LOGIN, realmId=37b0f797-510c-4e7b-915e-b7e21ea715f8, clientId=camp, userId=***, ipAddress=[ip of browser], auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, response_type=code, redirect_uri=https://***/my/web/page/?auth_callback=1, consent=no_consent_required, code_id=1a559718-1fd6-4b28-8088-aec7c58fc19a, username=***, response_mode=query, authSessionParentId=1a559718-1fd6-4b28-8088-aec7c58fc19a, authSessionTabId=zBPRbp4QclI

16:23:28,710 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-428) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=37b0f797-510c-4e7b-915e-b7e21ea715f8, clientId=camp, userId=***, ipAddress=[ip of server], error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=1a559718-1fd6-4b28-8088-aec7c58fc19a, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

After waiting a short time or appending some bogus query parameters to the URL or adding a trailing backslash (I'm not sure that any of those things actually "fixes" the problem), I eventually access the Web page successfully without being challenged to authenticate again. I noticed the following in my Keycloak log when I finally successfully get to the Web page:

```
16:23:46,784 INFO [org.keycloak.events] (default task-428) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN, realmId=37b0f797-510c-4e7b-915e-b7e21ea715f8, clientId=camp, userId=***, ipAddress=[ip of server], token_id=ba9745a2-9884-42b3-97cc-d1e425e552dd, grant_type=authorization_code, refresh_token_type=Refresh, scope='openid profile email roles', refresh_token_id=5d00ead5-8764-4d6a-a0f1-71161efc3360, code_id=1a559718-1fd6-4b28-8088-aec7c58fc19a, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

Note that this log entry is for a Refresh. I'm not really sure why the initial auth request fails, but finally succeeds with a refresh request. It looks like the initial authentication request succeeds, but fails when getting the access token. But then the request to refresh the access token succeeds?

There's clearly something I don't understand here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is due to the fact that my application is running in a cluster. I'm guessing (still have to prove this) that part of the OIDC protocol is handled by one node or the other and some state is lost which results in Keycloak thinking that the code is invalid. As a test, I reduced the number of nodes to 1 and now can't reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was still using a MemoryStore (the default for express-session) from before I deployed this to a cluster. Guess I need to read my own code a bit more closely. I switched to a database-backed session store and everything works fine now.